# Filter foreign key date django_filters

Tags: python, django, django-filter

Currently my filter works so I can filter on name.
However I also want to filter on releases (So display game that has release.date between a certain range)

How can I do that?

filters.py

```
class ReleaseFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    date =  django_filters.DateFromToRangeFilter(field_name='date') 

    class Meta:
        model = Release
        fields = ['date']

class GameFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    name = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    releases = ReleaseFilter()

    class Meta:
        model = Game
        fields = ['releases']
```

models.py

```
class Game(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Release(models.Model):
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, related_name='releases', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()
```

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is define the filter field with [`distinct=True`](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/filters.html#distinct):

> This option can be used to eliminate duplicate results when using filters that span relationships.

Example:

```py
release_date = django_filters.DateFromToRangeFilter(field_name='releases__date', distinct=True)
```

Full working example on [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@frankie567/drf-filters-distinct). Query result example: https://drf-filters-distinct--frankie567.repl.co/games/?release_date_after=2019-01-01&release_date_before=2019-12-31

Answer (score 0):

```
releases__date = django_filters.DateFromToRangeFilter()
```

Did the trick for me

But the problem is if I sort on it, I see duplicates in the game list. Since it outputs a game for every release date

Answer (score -1):

You can use built-in model filter to do that
Like as (for greater or equal than `date`)

```
Game.objects.filter(release__date__gte=date)
```

Comment: i think you can find some answer here https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/issues/1023